# Proxy password containing `@` in JVM

Tags: java, scala, proxy, jvm

I have some Scala code that has managed to successfully negotiate the (NTLM) proxy and access the internet, specifying the username and password as so:

```
// Based upon http://rolandtapken.de/blog/2012-04/java-process-httpproxyuser-and-httpproxypassword
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

  override protected def getPasswordAuthentication: PasswordAuthentication = {

    if (getRequestorType eq RequestorType.PROXY) {
      val prot = getRequestingProtocol.toLowerCase

      // This allows us to only return a PasswordAuthentication when we have
      // all four of the host, port, user and password _and_ the host and
      // port match the actual proxy wanting authentication.
      for {
        host <- Option(System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyHost"))
        if getRequestingHost.equalsIgnoreCase(host)
        port <- Try(augmentString(System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyPort")).toInt).toOption
        if port == getRequestingPort
        user <- Option(System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyUser"))
        pass <- Option(System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyPassword"))
      } yield return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass.toCharArray)
    }

    // One of the if-statements failed.  No authentication for you!
    null
  }
})
```

However, I've now been given a new system username/password combination to use, and the password contains an `@` in it.  I've tried using the password directly, escaping it (with both `\` and `\\` in case a double-level of escaping was needed), url-encoding it (i.e. replacing `@` with `%40`) and even HTML-encoding (`&commat;` and `&#64;`) to no avail.

I know the password works, as it's used on other systems for non-JVM applications to access the internet by setting the `http_proxy` variable, but it doesn't work here.

Any ideas?

---

### EDIT

To try and clear some things up, I've tried simplifying my code to this:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

  def urlEncode(str: String): String = {
    val res = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8")
    // To confirm it's working
    println(s"${str} -> ${res}")
    res
  }

  override protected def getPasswordAuthentication: PasswordAuthentication = {

    if (getRequestorType eq RequestorType.PROXY) {

      return new PasswordAuthentication(urlEncode("username"), urlEncode("p@ssword").toCharArray);
    }
    null
  }

})
```

The environment that this is being run in is in a Spark cluster (run with `spark-submit`) on a Linux box.  The proxy is a corporate NTLM one.

If I use known a username and password combination that doesn't contain `@` then this works.  If I change it to one containing an `@` then it fails.

I've tried making `val res = str` inside the `urlEncode` function (in case it doesn't need to be URL encoded), tried having `\\@` (with and without URL encoding) and `^@` (with and without URL encoding).  Every single time I get an exception of `Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required"`.

I know that the username and password are valid as they are currently set in the `https_proxy` variable that is successfully used by curl, etc.

So unless the fact that the proxy is being set within a running Spark server somehow affects what happens to it, it appears to me that the JVM libraries do not support having `@` in the authenticator for proxies (at the very least).

Comment: You could capture the network traffic between the failing Java client and the Proxy, and between a successful client and the Proxy, and compare the two. It will be difficult to analyse, as NTLM is a challenge-response protocol, but it might in theory allow you to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I've started doing that, but the traffic is a pain to slog through.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not within the `java.net` library code (EDIT: certainly for HTTP Basic proxies, I have not yet been able to test NTLM proxies). The `java.net` code can connect fine using passwords with "@" in them. I have put demo code below that allows you to verify this claim.

You do not need to escape the string value that you pass into `java.net.PasswordAuthentication`, you should pass your password in plaintext there. The `java.net` library code will take care of encoding your password as necessary when sending it over the network to the proxy (see demo code below to verify this claim).

I believe that your problem must be in the way that you are configuring your system outside of the code that you have included in the question so far.

For example, have you passed the proxy hostname to the JVM or a nearby system in such a way that it is confused by the "@" symbol?

Please can you provide more context?

### Demo code to verify that the java.net library code can cope with "@" in the password

This code includes instructions on setting up Fiddler2 as an HTTP proxy on your local machine, configuring Fiddler2 to require a password, and connecting through that proxy using the java.net library classes.

The code runs successfully for me as-is, and fails if I change the "password" variable to an incorrect password.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;

public class q45749081 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Start Fiddler HTTP proxy https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler
        // Click "rules" -> "require proxy authentication"
        // Type into the "QuickExec" box below Fiddler's Web Sessions list:
        //    prefs set fiddler.proxy.creds dXNlcm5hbWU6cEBzc3dvcmQ=
        //
        // This sets Fiddler to require auth with "username", "p@ssword"
        //
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259969/changing-username-and-password-of-fiddler-proxy-server

        // Note that you must start a new process each time you change the password
        // here, as sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection caches the proxy password
        // for the lifetime of the JVM process
        String password = "p@ssword";

        System.out.println(
            "prefs set fiddler.proxy.creds " +
            Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:p@ssword".getBytes()));

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                    "username",
                    password.toCharArray());
            }
        });


        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");

        System.out.println("Connecting to Google via authenticated proxy with password '"
            + password + "'");
        try (InputStream conn = new URL("http://www.google.com/").openStream()) {
            try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn))) {
                System.out.println(r.readLine());
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

### First answer:

The code you have shown is taking the password from a JVM System property. How are you putting your password into that property? I suspect the problem lies there, rather than in the code you have shown.

If you are on Windows, and if you are setting the password as a command-line argument, you will need to use the DOS escape char "^", i.e.

```
java -Dhttp.proxyPassword=foo^@bar -jar myapp.jar
```

If you use another mechanism to provide the password to Java, you may need a different escaping scheme.

Comment: This is all on Linux, not Windows (hence why I tried using backslash to escape).  Specifically, this is part of a Spark job that I'm submitting and specifying this system property using `--driver-java-options='-Dhttps.proxyPassword="p@ssword" ...'`.  I did just try with a caret just in case but no dice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm reasonably sure that your problem is how to escape this string as it makes its way through the various parameter layers, and doesn't actually have anything to do with HTTP Proxies at all. Can you log the value of the "proxyPassword" system property at app startup time to a) confirm this hypothesis and b) allow you to try different escaping schemes more quickly and with clearer feedback?

Comment: I have done so, and it looks right as it gets printed before it goes into the `PasswordAuthentication`.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have posted so far. I have updated my answer. Good luck!

Comment: OK, I've managed to modify your solution to match my environment (corporate proxy, same box that I'm trying to run it from, etc.) and it still works, so it must be something to do with going through the Spark server.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon; looks like the caching was going on as even after I changed the password (to one that was wrong), re-compiled and re-ran it it was still working; so I'll have to wait until the proxy server stops letting me through automatically and try again.

Comment: So I've tried again, and I get `Failed: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required"`.  Are you able to test with https (not sure if Fiddler supports that) as opposed to http? Unsure if it's an https issue, doesn't work with NTLM-based proxies or something specific to my setup.

Comment: I can't easily set up an NTLM-based proxy, no. There is a known bug in Java with HTTPS and NTLM-based http proxies, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326849/java-6-ntlm-proxy-authentication-and-https-has-anyone-got-it-to-work and similar on the net. I think that maybe you should just ask the admin to change the password, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid that, as our admins can be a pain... I've awarded you the bounty for your help (thanks!) but not going to accept the answer in case someone is able to come up with an actual solution.

Comment: Thanks. I have had a look through the code in `sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm` (I assume you are using the standard Sun JVM?) and it looks to me like the JVM code should work fine with passwords with "@" in them. I still suspect that your problem here is a setup or usage issue and not an insurmountable bug in the JVM itself, but I can't do much more without a repro case to fiddle with. I have raised https://serverfault.com/questions/871085/looking-for-a-lightweight-ntlm-http-proxy-server