# What is username and password for Fiddler's 'Require Proxy Authentication'?

Tags: fiddler

I start Fiddler and go to cnn.com in my browser - no problem. Fiddler has auto-configured he browser to go thru Fiddler as a proxy. Good.

When I go to Fiddler > Rules > Require Proxy Authentication, I start getting prompted for a username and password, which is almost what I expected, and kind of cool.

So, what is that username and password?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing username and password of fiddler proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259969/changing-username-and-password-of-fiddler-proxy-server)

Answer (score 1):

The linked question is related, and my question is more or less answered in that answer, but this will be more clear:

```
username: 1
password: 1
```